# Change Text Area Value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How could I change the value of a text area through jQuery. Here is a sample:

```
var content = "Hello World";
//Code to set the value of the 
text area to content here.
```

How would I do this through jQuery or just javascript? An answer is appreciated, thanks.
I tried this:

```
var txtArea = document.getElementById('aTextArea');
txtArea.value = rolls;
```

However, that was just a shot in the dark.

Comment: where is you code to textarea? what have you tried?

Comment: If "aTextArea" is the ID of a textarea element and there are no other elements in your page with that ID as `name` or `id` attributes, your code is guaranteed to work. There is nothing broken about the `value` property of textareas in any major browser.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming your textarea as

```
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50">
   sample textarea
</textarea>​​​​​​
```

jquery code to update textarea value would be

```
 ​$(document).ready(function(){
    var content = "Hello World";
    $("#textarea").val(content);
});​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhatlx/PuWH4/1/

Comment: @kaveman: Ok, thanks for the link. textarea is not a common input element I use, so could not remember the attributes and had to go there

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, and why the w3fools link, kaveman?

Comment: I was using textarea tag example from w3schools. so he posted it.

Comment: Could you adjust the rows and cols dynamically while the textarea is in use?

Answer (score 3):

**jQuery**

With jQuery you can use [`.val("Your new value")`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on textareas as well, even if the HTML-element doesn't have a value-attribute.

```
$(function(){
   $("#id-of-textarea").val("test");
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sfxTt/

**Plain JavaScript**

With plain JS, it could be done like this:

```
document.getElementById('id-of-textarea').value = "Hello";
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sfxTt/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("textarea[name='message_text_reply']").val('Holla')
```

This works very well for me where input attribute name is `message_text_reply`, the `$("#message_text_reply")` option is not working .